# ProgrammingError when using sqlalchemy.create_engine() in __init__(self)

Tags: python, class, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

The methods work fine in a single function, but it breaks if I try to implement it in a class.

```
class SqlDownload():
    
    def __init__(self):
        driver="ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
        connection_url = f"database?driver={driver}"
        self.engine = sa.create_engine(connection_url)
    
    def get_uploaded(self):
        engine = self.engine
        query = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM [db_Dev].[de].[ti]"
        df = pd.read_sql(sql=query, con=engine)
        uploaded_list = df["name"].to_list()
        return uploaded_list

d = SqlDownload()
d.get_uploaded()
```

The above does not work, but this does:

```
def get_uploaded():
        driver="ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
        connection_url = f"database?driver={driver}"
        engine = sa.create_engine(connection_url)
        query = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM [db_Dev].[de].[ti]"
        df = pd.read_sql(sql=query, con=engine)
        uploaded_list = df["name"].to_list()
        return uploaded_list

get_uploaded()
```

Why? How do I make it work with the class? I have other download functions that use the same connection/engine on different tables.

I'm getting this error (only for the former):

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'db_Dev.de.ti'

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create a new `engine` for every instance of your class. Don't do that.

Comment: `FROM` must be followed by a table name. That's either `[db].[table]` or just `[table]`. What is `[db_Dev].[de].[ti]` supposed to be?

Comment: @Barmar - that would be [database_name].[schema_name].[table_name]

Comment: @GordThompson Oops, my MySQL experience slipped through, it doesn't have separate db and schema.

Comment: In any case, the error message indicates that either the database, schema, or table doesn't exist.

Comment: @GordThompson how would you go about it? It worked great with pyodbc and the connection. Just make two functions without a class and have the whole engine code in both?

Comment: @Barmar it does say that but that's the confusing part as the latter version works with the exact same query.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it would make a difference whether you do it in the class or with the regular function. The same sequence of calls take place. I suspect something else is going on, and it's just a coincidence that it started failing when you switched to the class.

Comment: @GordThompson But in the non-class version, he creates a new engine every time he calls `get_uploaded()`. That's arguably even worse.

Comment: From [the tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/engine.html): "The engine is typically a global object created just once for a particular database server"